# How can I pass an object as parameter to apiary?

Tags: object, apiary

I tried to pass an object as parameter to apiary, but it doesn't work correctly. I am a new user to apiary editor and I need your help!

The request body is:

```
{
    callbackUrl = "http://test.com",
    dlr = true,
    option1 = "option 1",
    option2 = "option 2",
    { "306936XXXXXX", "306936XXXXXX" },
    dateinToSend = 20180101,
    timeinToSend = 1000,
    sms = new SmsObj
    {
        sender = "Demo",
        text = " This is a test sms fallback",
        validity = 100,
        typesms = "sms",
        priority = 1
    },
}
```

and in apiary's editor I wrote the below:

## Group Send Method

- Parameters

  - phonenumbers: XXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXXXXXXX (required, array)
  - dateinToSend: `20180101` (optional, Integer)
  - timeinToSend: `20180101` (optional, Integer)
  - dlr: `true` (optional, Bool)
  - callbackUrl: `http://test.com` (optional, string)
  - option1: `option 1` (optional, string)
  - option2: `option 2` (optional, string)
  - sms: (optional, SmsObj Object)

    - sender: `Demo` (required, string)
    - text: `text` (required, string)
    - validity: `100` (optional, integer)
    - typesms: `sms` (optional, string)
    - longsms: `false` (optional, bool)
    - priority: `1` (optional, integer)

I believe that the problem is that the object "sms" doesn't pass correct through the post request.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much for your help!